# Why won't macvim always use ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, vim, macvim

I have installed [yadr dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles), a set of vim, ruby, etc plugins.

I have the following line of Ruby code in a file `foo.rb`:

`foo: bar`

Note I used the ruby 1.9.3 syntax for symbol assignment/definition.

When I start macvim from command line using `mvim foo.rb` and save that file, everything works fine.

However, when I open macvim using `open -a macvim` and navigate to and open `foo.rb`, when I try to save the file I get a ruby-vim syntax error on `foo: bar`. When I change it to `:foo => bar` I don't get syntax errors.

- Using `open -a macvim` to open macvim, and then entering `:!ruby -v` prints `ruby 1.8.7`
- Using `mvim .` to open macvim, and then entering `:!ruby -v` prints `ruby 1.9.3`

*Depending on how I open macvim, I get a different version of Ruby*. How do I ensure that macvim always uses ruby 1.9.3 to evaluate my ruby code?

Thanks

Comment: What does `:!echo $PATH` show in each?

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because I forgot most of the details but the two methods are loading different environment variables: `mvim file` uses your shell's environment while `open -a macvim files` uses your system's environment. But why would you use it? `mvim` is infinitely better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me awhile to find a fix, but the issue is caused by MacVim not loading zsh the same way Terminal loads zsh.

The fix is easy enough and can be placed into your zshrc. See a commit from my dotfiles:

https://github.com/simeonwillbanks/dotfiles/commit/e0e19cfeff13f8bc99d8164217ddd84c6d7f9529

The commit references a full explanation which can be found here:

http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacVim-and-PATH-tt3388705.html#a3392363

[image]

Hope this helps!